# IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'Number', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.String'. Reading: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.jti

Tags: c#, jwt, servicestack, identitymodel

After updating all NuGet packages (to ServiceStack 6.11, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 7.3.1, Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 7.3.1, and more) I get the following error message on the client:

```
IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string.
```

In the debugger I found this message:

```
IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'Number', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.String'. Reading: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.jti', Position: '144', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '145'.'
```

The payload which is trying to be parsed is (I've masked name and preferred_username).

```
{ 
  "iss": "ssjwt", 
  "sub": null, 
  "iat": 1707237670, 
  "exp": 1707241270, 
  "name": "xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx", 
  "preferred_username": "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "jti": 4, 
  "OriginalProvider": "msalauth" 
}
```

I think the issue is the "jti" claim which is returned as a number instead of a string by the ServiceStack service. I've checked with older versions of the ServiceStack service, and it has always been a number.

In System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.cs the following code snippet is reading the value as a string instead of a number:

```
else if (reader.ValueTextEquals(JwtPayloadUtf8Bytes.Jti)) { 
  payload._jti = JsonSerializerPrimitives.ReadString(ref reader, JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, ClassName, true);
  payload[JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti] = payload._jti; 
}
```

I've posted this issue here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2401, but they replied that the "jti" JWT ID should be a string as specified here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.html#section-4.1.7

Where is the JWT ID added in the claims by ServiceStack and can I change the datatype?
Or should the datatype be changed in the ServiceStack package?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to use a `string` for jti by overriding `ResolveJwtId` and `ResolveRefreshJwtId` when registering the JWT Auth Provider:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), 
[
    new JwtAuthProvider(appSettings) {
        ResolveJwtId = _ => Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        ResolveRefreshJwtId = _ => Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    }, 
]));
```

Although it's not recommended to read ServiceStack JWT Tokens with external libraries. Instead if you need compatibility we recommend using [ServiceStack JWT Identity Auth](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v8_01#jwt-identity-auth) from ServiceStack v8.1+ which uses ASP.NET Core's JWT Configuration and implementation to implement its JWT support.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. We are still using .NET framework 4.8, but are planning to update all our API services to .NET core within the next year. We can then reevaluate the authentication libraries.